# recommend math books

Tags: reference-request, self-learning, recreational-mathematics, education

So i completed an year ago my schooling and i am pretty good at maths well at my level and i am very interested in maths and want to learn as much maths as possible and i like stuff like number theory. what got me really fueled up is the fact that i watched a video on numberphile (its a youtube channel on math stuff) about prime numbers and i got goosebumps when i heard that they have a formula that approximately calculates n'th prime number i thought prime numbers follow no pattern and bad thing i did not understand that formula ....
well not to go with the story and all so the thing is i want to study more of mathematics by my own so i need you all to recommend me good books to get firm hold of every topic in math i not very hifi stuff that i want to start low and then become a jedi that does not mean i need books for noobs to understand what my math level is consider these things so that you may help me in a better way to recommend books

- i do know $e^{iθ}= \cos θ + i\sin θ$ and its proof using expansions of $\sin  x, \cos x$ and $e^x$
- i do have basic knowledge about parabola, circle, straight lines(and pair of straight lines), ellipse and hyperbola(although i don't like them idk why)
- basic trignometry

now my thinking levels

- i once tried to calculate a algorithm or formula that would give equation of circle that would have maximum overlap with a parabola and passes through its vertex(failed miserably)

  - tried to calculate function that would give distance(not displacement you have to follow along curve) between any two points on curve of sine graph(not failed actually a computer would be able to calculate using that infinite sum to some accuracy but still failed)

well that should be enough i would ideally like books that would assume i know basics and then follow up but books that do start from very basic and get to pro are good to but not the ones that do not tell me what i already know but are just filled with much difficult problems based on what i do know i want although problem solving is must for math and i am not saying i don't want that in  books you recommend i do want them and lots of problems but you get it what i am trying to say well go for it !!!!

Comment: **tl;dr**: "Just finished highschool and have a good understanding of most highschool level topics, and would like you to recommend books on slightly more advanced topics."

Comment: not highschool whole schooling

Comment: only if you read more you would know and why are you mocking me i am trying to learn here

Comment: @user306284 does that mean you recently graduated from college/university?  It's important that we know how much math you know if we're going to recommend something at your level.

Comment: @user306284 I did in fact read read your whole post, and I am not mocking but rather trying to help you get more answers.

Comment: well not collage  just schooling we call it "12th class" here and i am not a grad not just sitting at home after completing my schooling preparing for competitive exams

Comment: @Omnomnomnom read the last list you would know

Comment: @user306284 In the US, we call the last classes (classes 9-12) "high school".  Hence, we would consider you a recent (or upcoming) high-school graduate.

Comment: @user306284 that does not give us an accurate representation of the (level of) classes you have taken.

Comment: well then i think the only way is you ask me math questions and i will respond and then you decide what level i am at (not a genius )

Comment: @user306284 try this maybe, https://www.math.brown.edu/~jhs/frint.html.

Comment: @user306284 As Daniel said, what you've posted isn't enough information.  For example, your first bullet could indicate that you had a particular interest in the one famous identity.  It could also indicate that you have a basic understanding of the theory behind Taylor/MacLauren series.  It could also indicate that you have a deep understanding of the theory behind analytic functions.

Comment: @Daniel i will bookmarked it

Comment: @Omnomnomnom i don't have very deep knowledge about taylor expansion but i do understand how it works like you consider the function to be a nth degree polynomial and then work on finding those coefficients putting 0 in function to find the constant and then differentiating it to get rid of it then again putting zero to get coefficient of unity power and as we do this the power of the variable x multiplies along so we need to divide we factorials as we move further thats all i know

Comment: @user306284 The best indication of what you know is which bodies of mathematical techniques you've learned ("basic rules of differentiation", "integration by parts", those sort of things).  I'd say that your inherent ability doesn't tell us what you should learn next; rather, it tells us how quickly you learn.

Comment: @user306284 at any rate, linear algebra might be a good next stop for you

Comment: so what do i do i suggest you ask me questions based (preferably on calculus or 2-d co ordinate geometry ) and judge me

Comment: @Omnomnomnom books you would like me to read ?

Comment: @user306284 Well...since you mentioned *Number theory* in your question...you can easily get list of good books on this topic on this site ....there are some really good suggestions there...

Comment: And even though I can't recommend any such books ...but as far as inspiration goes ....well **The man who only loved numbers** is a really good book....you can read it in your free time ...I read it partially in class 11th...and it was very inspiring...

Comment: i will read it .

Comment: @user306284 I'd say Daniel's suggestion is a good one, and decently challenging.

Comment: Many of the books listed at http://www.maa.org/press/ebooks/anneli-lax-new-mathematical-library are good for people at the high school level before they move on to more advanced topics like calculus. I know numbers 1, 3, 8, 15, 19 and 20 are good. The books *Functions and Graphs* and *Algebra* by Gelfand are also good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good starting point, covering lots of topics in first/second year college math, are the various [lecture notes](https://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/~maths/Chen-notes/ln.html) by William Chen. Well written, clearly explained.

Kenneth Bogart's ["Combinatorics through Guided Discovery"](http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/news-resources/electronic/kpbogart/ComboNoteswHints11-06-04.pdf) is a nice introduction to it's topic, geared towards self-study.

If you want to be dazzled by a broad variety of ingenious reasoning, perhaps Aigner and Ziegler's "Proofs from THE BOOK" (Springer, 5th edition 2014) is what you are looking for. You need some higher math to fully understand it.

If you want a flavour of how math became what it is today, Dunham's "Journey through genius" (Penguin Books, reprint 1991) could be a good starting point.

In any case, "I want to learn more math" is awfully broad. Today's mathematics has splintered into dozens, if not hundreds, of subtopics, each of whose detailed exploration can (and does) take a lifetime. Do you want to get a leg up for college? Go for Chen's notes. Want to learn more in depth, explore some types of stuff that aren't in high-school main fare? Go for Bogart's. Both available for free. You might also check out [open culture's textbooks](http://www.openculture.com/free-math-textbooks).

Answer (score 4):

You say you like number theory so, try [*A Friendly Introduction to Number Theory*](https://www.math.brown.edu/~jhs/frint.html) as a start. If you like this, follow it up with [*Elementary Number Theory, David M Burton*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0073383147).

Also you may be interested in Linear Algebra, and this would be a good step into more advanced maths. For this you can try [*Linear Algebra and Its Applications, 4th Edition*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0030105676).